# Can we pass any method except void in thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am working on a thread. I have a method:

```
private int Calculate(int number);
can I used this method in a thread ?
Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Calculate));
```

We can't do that as ThreadStart() only accept void method. So, Is there any way to handle it using thread ? Also, If Calculate is void method, how can i pass argument in

```
thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Calculate));
```

Comment: Which version of C# are you using? The Task Parallel Library is recommended above using Threads manually. They also have nice support for returning values.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ParameterizedThreadStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart.aspx) and change the int type parameter to object and cast it back to int.

```
private int Calculate(object number)
{
   int num = Convert.ToInt32(number);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use lambdas and the compiler will infer its type:

```
Thread t = new Thread(() => Calculate(number));
```

Comment: Ok.. the above code works for void method. What If the methode is of return type. for e.g.
private int Calculate(int number)

Comment: That still works, because the lambda's signature matches ThreadStart (takes no params, returns void). Calculate()'s signature is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

Captured variables work well:

```
  int number = 42;
  var thread = new Thread(() => Calculate(number));
```